# CSS boxes collapsing while zooming out

Tags: css, alignment, zooming

I have a problem related to zooming out on the webpages I am working with.

When the page is zoomed out the boxes are misaligned

**Normal Look:**

[image]

**While Zooming Out:**

[image]

**Div Structure**

```
<div class="answerbox shadow">
<div class="content">
<p>What is an Annuity and how does it help with my retirement income?</p>
</div>
<p> <a class="more" href="aboutannunities">Find Out More</a></p></div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.answerbox {
    height: 125px;
 /*Specify Height*/
    width: 250px;
 /*Specify Width*/
    border: 1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient (rgb(20, 255, 255), rgb(230, 230, 230)) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(20, 255, 255), rgb(230, 230, 230)) repeat scroll** 0 0 transparent;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(20, 255, 255)), to(rgb(230, 230, 230))) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 /* older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(20, 255, 255), rgb(230, 230, 230)) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 7px;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    background: #E6E6E9;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#FFFFFF ), to(#E6E6E9));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF , #E6E6E9);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF , #E6E6E9);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF , #E6E6E9);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF , #E6E6E9);
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF , #E6E6E9);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF , #E6E6E9);
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Any ideas/suggestions/help will be thankful...

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 540px;float:left;">
```

Add this in in your CSS:

```
.answerbox {
    float:left;
 .....
```

And try with following code:

```
<div style="width: 540px;float:left;">

     <div class="answerbox shadow">
     <div class="content">
         <p>What is an Annuity and how does it help with my retirement income?</p>
     </div>
     <p> <a class="more" href="aboutannunities">Find Out More</a></p></div>


<div class="answerbox shadow">
    <div class="content">
        <p>What is an Annuity and how does it help with my retirement income?</p>
    </div>
   <p> <a class="more" href="aboutannunities">Find Out More</a></p></div>

</div>
```

Comment: No Kumar... It's not working... I believe we need to change something else.. Any other idea on this plz /

Comment: what I have posted, it is working for me. Have you set the width for outer DIV?

Comment: Yes... I implemented the same what you have provided... Still, its not working.. :-(

Comment: Have you set the width for outer DIV?